# how to get an HTML element who called a function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have HTML elements with 'onclick' attribute like this one:

```
  <div class="item add pt-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal" 
   onclick="myFunction();"><i class="ni ni-fat-add"></i></div>
```

Later in a script I want to have `this` element to manipulate it.

```
myFunction(){  
  $(theElement).data('target'); //example
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send it in:

```
onclick="myFunction(this);"
```

And then you get it as the first argument to your function:

```
function myFunction(theElement) {
  $(theElement).data('target');
}
```

But you should consider adding the event with JavaScript in the first place:

```
<div class="item add pt-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal">...</div>
```

And your JavaScript file could contain something like:

```
// add click listeners to all DOM elements that have the class "add"
$('.add').on('click', function() {
  $(this).data('target');
});
```

Or without jQuery, and modern JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.add').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    el.dataset.target;
  });
});
```

If the element is dynamically created, then you could consider using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: thank you very much. Just didn't work with jQ for a while, and forgot this simple way)

Comment: @AndrewBro [tag:jq] and [tag:jquery] are two different things, [tag:jq] usually refers to a command line tool that are used to manipulate JSON, while [tag:jquery] is a JavaScript framework

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction(myEvent){  
 console.log( myEvent.getAttribute('data-toggle')) 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item add pt-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal" 
   onclick="myFunction(this);"><i class="ni ni-fat-add"></i>click me</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't refer to the global variable `event` as it's deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event